# How to concatenate array objects and strings to get a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, firebase

The following code is supposed to take a string as an input(inMessage here) and split the words in it. It then queries firebase realtime database for an associated key, value and replaces the word with the value retrieved. This modified string has to be sent back as output.

Now, I can't seem to find a way to make the 'msg' a proper string. If I hardcode a string instead of msg I get the output rendered correctly. So how do I make msg a proper string? (I've tried enclosing it with "", toString(), String() and JSON.stringify() - There has to be something I'm missing here)

```
  function queryDB(senderID, inMessage){
    var arr=inMessage.split(" ");
    console.log(arr);
    var i;
    console.log('inside queryDB');
    var msg="";
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var x = 'https://oreo-fd681.firebaseio.com/'+arr[i]+'.json';
    request({
        url: x,
        method: 'GET'
      }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(response.body);
            if (error) {
              console.log('Error making api call ' + error);
            } else if (response.body.error){
              console.log('Error making api call' + response.body.error);
            }
            else if(response==null)  {
              //if not found in DB concatenate whatever arr[i] holds
              callback1();
            }
            else  {
              //else concatenate the found key
              var n=JSON.parse(response.body);
              //remove the quotes associated with key value
              callback2(JSON.stringify(n.key).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
            }
      }); 
      function callback1(){
        msg+=(arr[i]);
        msg+=" ";
        console.log(msg);
      }
      function callback2(add){
        msg+=(add);
        msg+=" ";
        console.log(msg);
      }
    }
      //add quotes back - not sure of this
      sendMessageToUser(senderID, ("\""+msg+"\""));  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are related with the asynchronous nature of the `request` callback:

- You execute `sendMessageToUser` before any of the requests has returned a result.
- Because `i` is declared with `var`, the value for `i` will reach `arr.length` before any of the requests has returned a result, so in `callback1` that value will be useless -- it will always reference `arr[arr.length]`, which is undefined
- Assuming that the returned keys are strings, there is no reason to first stringify those as JSON and then remove the quotes. In fact, if a key contains quotes, then those will be lost in that process.
- There is no guarantee that the responses to the requests will come back in the same order. So doing `msg +=` may well build a string that has the keys in the wrong order.
- Not a bug, but creating functions within a loop should be kept to a minimum. So I would not use `callback1` and `callback2` like that.

Below is one way to do it, which sticks to the plain old callback pattern. It has these changes:

- It collects the keys in an array first, so that you can put a key at exactly the index where it belongs. This way the order in which the responses come in does not matter; the array will at the end still have them in the right order.
- It keeps track of how many responses we are still waiting for to come in. That way you can known when you have received everything and then call `sendMessageToUser`
- The variable `i` is declared with `let` within the `for` construct, so that it has block scope, i.e. you get a separate variable for each iteration of the loop. This way, when you reference it in a callback, it will be to exactly that version of the variable.
- The `callback1` and `callback2` functions are replaced with code that can deal with the two variations (when `response === null` or not).

Here is the code:

```
function queryDB(senderID, inMessage){
    var arr = inMessage.split(" ");
    console.log(arr);
    console.log('inside queryDB');
    // At first, use an array, so you can put back the asynchronous results in the correct order
    var msgArray = [];
    // Keep track of the number of asynchronous results you are still waiting for
    var leftOver = arr.length;
    // Use LET to make loop variable block scoped: that way you'll have the same value for
    //   it when the asynchronous callback is called
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var x = 'https://oreo-fd681.firebaseio.com/'+arr[i]+'.json';
        request({
            url: x,
            method: 'GET'
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(response.body);
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error making api call ' + error);
            } else if (response.body.error){
                console.log('Error making api call' + response.body.error);
            }
            else {
                // Treat the two cases with the ternary operator
                //  and put the result at the correct index
                msgArray[i] = response === null ? arr[i] : JSON.parse(response.body).key;
                console.log(msgArray);
                // Detect when you have collected all results
                leftOver--;
                if (!leftOver) {
                    // Join all the words together into one string and send it
                    sendMessageToUser(senderID, msgArray.join(' '));  
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Like I said, I stuck to the callback pattern, but things become nicer when you use promises and the `Promise.all` method. You should look into that.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks @trincot :) You missed to declare 'n' in your code though. Will look into Promise.all

Comment: Ah yes, I now replaced `n` with the expression it should be.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be an issue. Try replacing

```
msg+= (arr[i]);
```

with

```
msg = msg.concat(arr[i]);
```

use concat in all four `msg +=` assignments

if your `arr` values are numeric values it could be adding numbers instead.